Play media file using expiring url in Android
I have a list of urls that will expire in 5 minutes and I want to make a playlist from these urls. The thing is that each media is longer than 5 minutes. And I wonder how could I possibly do that?
By now I am creating a playlist by time I got all the links. But I am not sure if MediaItem cares whether the link it uses should be available when it starts playing. So the question is how to properly do this?
I tried to make a playlist from urls as fast as I get them so that each url is still not expired. But the first audio I get is like 1.5 hours long.
And the main question is when does ExoPlayer and MediaItem get all the required data from url, because I couldn’t find any info about this.

Based on the MediaPlayer lifecycle, you could async load the content:
lifecycleScope.launch {
withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
    setDataSource(url)
    prepareAsync()
    setOnPreparedListener {
        play() // you have to write this function yourself
    }
}
}
}

Based on your mismatch between iOS and Android library terminology, I might also recommend using Kotlin Multiplatform so you can develop all the code once.  There's a new sound library that should help with this.

The use case states that the URL expires in 5 minutes. Are you able to programmatically perform a 'refresh' to fetch a new, unexpired URL?
If so then you will need to describe the media using fields such as MediaItem.mediaId, and implement a custom DataSourceFactory.
In the custom DataSourceFactory you would create a custom DataSource / DataReader. The implementation of the custom DataReader's read method is where the 'refresh' logic would be placed, i.e. use the current URL, if it fails due to expiration then fetch a new URL (which becomes the current one until expiration time).

Update:
Exoplayer's networking layer will be making a HTTP range request, which is already handled by okhttp. I suggest studying OkHttpDataSource.open(). You could customize that method with your own logic that intercepts DataSpec.uri and "re-writes" it with an unexpired URL. This re-writing of the URL would be seamless for the user.

I am able to fetch new urls from code. My main question is it is somehow possible to fetch new urls seamless for user? I know that exoplayer buffer some data and is it possible to know where buffering stops and continue load from that point?

Hi Гендальф Серый, please see the update to the answer ^^^
